# Compile: lnk2001 with webrtc.lib

Tags: windows, webrtc

I have succeeded to compile webrtc native lib through the official document, but when I linked webrtc.lib in my project. I got these errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgepe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to build the library with clang and lld disabled. Try generating the build config with:

`gn gen out/Default --args="is_clang=false use_lld=false"`